# PHP создает нулевой  элемент массива

Tags: массивы, php

есть код выдирающий id объекта и создающий из них массив. (првоеренно создает правильно вида:

`[1: "2", 2: "10", 3: "18"]` )

передаем это массив из `js` в `php`:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: path_shell,
            cache:false,
            data:{flag_iq:3,arr_ans:Tests.iq_answer},
            success: function(data)

            {
                console.log(data);
            }
```

в php соответсвенно ловим

```
if(isset($_POST['flag_iq']) and $_POST['flag_iq']==3){

    $answer_arr=$_POST['arr_ans'];
    print_r ($_POST['arr_ans']);
```

при выводе пишет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 2
)
```

откуда берется этот 0 и как его убрать?)

Comment: Уже засыпаю, так что не уверен в правильности совета. Вечером напишу, если никто ничего путного не ответит. Кстати, попробуйте просто удалить нулевой элемент.

    unset($arr_ans[0]);

Comment: unset($arr_ans[0]);
 сработало. спасибо. Но все равно хотелось бы знать подоплеку происходящего. да и по сути это же костыль)

Comment: > [1: "2", 2: "10", 3: "18"]

это __не__ js-массив.
посмотрите в хроме, какие данные у вас реально уходят и какой запрос совершается.

Answer (score 1):

это всё потому-что php считает этот массив числовым, а вот этот phpшный массив-хэш очень странная штука. (может я ошибаюсь, посмотрите на  заголовки запроса) ну и в js нулевой элемент тоже видно, наберите

```
 var a=[];a[1]="a";a[2]="b";console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
 //[null,"a","b"]
```

вариант(если php не виноват) - использовать объект:

```
var a={};a[1]="a";a[2]="b";console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
//{"1":"a","2":"b"}
```